Bad Request 400 error while using Invoke Rest Post method of Graph API for uploading ipa file
I am trying to create an LOB [.ipa] app at Intune by calling Graph API through Powershell 2.
I am able to create the application at Intune but when I try to upload an ipa file, I receive:

Bad Request : 400 error.

Below is code snippet:
$tenantId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
$clientId = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
$clientSecret = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"

$appPath = "./Path to .ipa file" ## Relative Path
$resource = "https://graph.microsoft.com/"
$authUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token"

$authBody = @{   
   client_id     = $clientId
   client_secret = $clientSecret
   scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
   grant_type    = "client_credentials"
}
$tkResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $authUrl -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -Body $authBody
$origToken = $tkResponse.access_token

$initialheaders = @{
   Authorization = "Bearer $origToken"
   "Content-Type" = "application/json"
}
$body = @{
   "@odata.type" = "#microsoft.graph.iosLobApp"
   displayName = "Test"
   bundleId = "self.test.sample.app"
   buildNumber = "1.0.0"
   versionNumber = "1.0.0"
   description = "Test description"
   publisher = "Test Publisher"
   fileName = "Test.ipa"
   committedContentVersion = "1"
   informationUrl = "https://yourappwebsite.com"
   privacyInformationUrl = "https://yourappwebsite.com/privacy"
   minimumSupportedOperatingSystem = @{
       v8_0 = $true
   }
   applicableDeviceType = @{
       iPad = $true
       iPhoneAndIPod = $true
   }
}

$mobJson = $body | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
$graphApiUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceAppManagement/mobileApps"
try{
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $graphApiUrl -Headers $initialheaders -Body $mobJson -ErrorAction Stop -verbose
    $applicationId = $response.id
    } catch {
   Write-Host "$($_.Exception.Response.StatusCode)"
    }
`
        $fileUpUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/deviceAppManagement/mobileApps/$applicationId/contentVersions/1/files"

        $fContent = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($appPath)
        $baseContent = [Convert]::ToBase64String($fContent)

        $contheaders = @{
        Authorization = "Bearer $origToken"
        "Content-Type" = "application/octet-stream"
        }
            $uploadBody = @{
                       "@odata.type" = "#microsoft.graph.mobileAppContentFile"
                        name = (Get-Item $appPath).Name
                        sizeInBytes = (Get-Item $appPath).Length
                        versionCode = "1.0.0"
                        versionName = "Version Name"
                        contentBytes = $baseContent
                       } | ConvertTo-Json
      
     try{
            **## ERROR COMES FROM BELOW INVOKE METHOD ##**
               * $uploadResp = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $fileUpUrl -Method Post -Headers $contheaders -Body $uploadBody -Verbose*

        } catch {
                 $error = $_.Exception
    }


I also tried different ways like sending data as bytes, byte stream, sending body parameter as String but every time I receive "Bad Request : 400" error.

Application get created perfectly fine
Bad Request Error comes at second invoke rest method

Below is the error details
2024-12-23T18:16:34.9342611Z Error uploading IPA file: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
2024-12-23T18:16:34.9370301Z System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
2024-12-23T18:16:34.9372124Z    at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.GetResponse(WebRequest request)
2024-12-23T18:16:34.9392176Z    at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
2024-12-23T18:16:34.9404004Z Error11: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
2024-12-23T18:16:34.9404570Z    at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.GetResponse(WebRequest request)
2024-12-23T18:16:34.9405060Z    at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
2024-12-23T18:16:34.9406974Z Error11 Message: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
2024-12-23T18:16:34.9407299Z    at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.GetResponse(WebRequest request)
2024-12-23T18:16:34.9408070Z    at Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestPSCmdlet.ProcessRecord().Message


I don't think Invoke-RestMethod was available until PowerShell 3.0.  Are you sure you're using PowerShell 2.0 and not something like powershell.exe -Version 2.0?

Unfortunately, We are still using PowerShell 2.0

My apologies - Invoke-RestMethod was indeed available in PowerShell 2.0.  I'm curious -- have you tried uploading to that URL outside of PowerShell?

I believe that you need to create a temporary placeholder first as described in
the samples https://github.com/microsoftgraph/powershell-intune-samples/tree/master/LOB_Application point 2 and 3. Later on you replace it with your own file as detailed in instructions. In that moment you want to post to contentVersions/1/files it does not exist yet probably thats why you get error 400. You can troubleshoot further by trying to GET that file before POST.
